# how to count number of days via cron job in odoo 10?

Tags: python, odoo

I am setting up a script for counting number of days with passing each day in odoo.
How i can count day passing each day till end of the month.
For example : i have set two dates to find days between them.I need  function which compare number of days with each passing day. When meet remaining day is 0 then will call a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

Write a scheduled action that runs python code daily. The first thing that this code should do is to check the number of days you talk about and if it is 0, it should trigger whatever action it is needed.